# MarkLogic : DHF5 mlDeploy XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE: (err:XQDY0027) validate

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-10

We are trying to deploy our codebase which is currently on DHF 5.2.0 and we are getting below error :-

```
Local message: failed to apply resource at internal/apply-transform: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE: (err:XQDY0027) validate { $input } -- Invalid node type: @name lexical value "" invalid for expected type #m:parameterName at fn:doc("")/m:function-defs/m:function-def[1]/m:parameters/m:parameter[1]/@name using schema "mapping.xsd"
Error: com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at internal/apply-transform: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE: (err:XQDY0027) validate { $input } -- Invalid node type: @name lexical value "" invalid for expected type #m:parameterName at fn:doc("")/m:function-defs/m:function-def[1]/m:parameters/m:parameter[1]/@name using schema "mapping.xsd" in batch with urs ([/data-hub/5/mapping-functions/core-functions.xqy])

> Task :mlDeployApp FAILED
Job complete, jobBatchNumber=7, jobResultsSoFar=6
:mlDeployApp (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 2 mins 22.614 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlDeployApp'.
> com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at internal/apply-transform: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE: (err:XQDY0027) validate { $input } -- Invalid node type: @name lexical value "" invalid for expected type #m:parameterName at fn:doc("")/m:function-defs/m:function-def[1]/m:parameters/m:parameter[1]/@name using schema "mapping.xsd"
```

When we check the modules database we can see below files where it is point to the error :-

```
/data-hub/5/mapping-functions/core-functions.xqy
```

We didnt perform any changes to these files. Can anybody suggest how we can fix that ?

Command which we are running :-

```
gradle -i mlDeploy -PenvironmentName=AzureQual
```

Comment: Have you recently upgraded or changed versions?

Comment: Yes, We upgraded the DHF from 5.2.0 to 5.8.0, but here above we are deploying the code of 5.2.0 and getting the error.